# SearchView Refocusing Unintentionally

Tags: android, listview, focus, searchview

I can't post any code right now. My problem is that I have an Activity that implements  SearchView.OnQueryTextListener and SearchView.OnCloseListener. In the activity, I inflate a SearchView and a ListView. I don't relate them in anyway. I have code that toggles the visibility of the ListView. When I call this code, the SearchView gets refocused. If I removed that visibility code, it doesn't get refocused.

Is there something about SearchView I should know about in regards to refocusing?

Comment: when you remove thae visibility you can do this, i dont know if Works because you dont put any code. So try this  searchView.requestFocusFromTouch(); after set visibility

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"` to your top most layout in xml.